# mysql duplicar valor de campo

Tags: mysql

El caso es que quiero que dos campos concretos de diferentes tablas y con diferente nombre tenga el mismo valor continuamente, sin tener que hacer querys, es decir como si uno fuera la imagen del otro. ¿com podria hacerlo?.

Comment: ¿Te vale usar [vistas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)? ¿Por qué motivo deseas que tengan el mismo valor? ¿Para ahorrarte una consulta o por simplificar código? ¿Te valen los [iniciadores](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)?

Comment: Pues lo que pasa es que el programa con el que estoy es heredado y esta muy mal gestionado, hay cosas duplicadas por todos lados. El problema que tengo es que son dos campos en diferentes tablas con diferentes nombres de campo y de tabla pero que hacen referencia al mismo dato. Ademas hay querys de actualizacion y de consulta que apuntan cada una a un lugar y es imposible seguir todas las referencias que se hacen a dicho valor en el codigo. Mirare lo de los iniciadores pero las vistas no me valen.

Comment: ¿Qué referencia (clave primaria) tienen en común ambas tablas para facilitar la actualización entre ellas?

Comment: Si tienes libertad para reconstruir tus tablas/bases de datos lo mejor sería trazarte un plan de normalización de esos datos, en vez de seguir trabajando sobre ellos. Al final perderás más tiempo tratando de hacer que funcione el desastre que hay montado... sin saber qué tanto funcionará pero seguro que si lo hace será a un alto precio en rendimiento, en mantenimiento, en consumo de tiempo, etc etc. Hay muchísimas maneras de consultar esos datos mal introducidos, para irlos depurando, organizando, normalizando en base a un patrón, a un plan. Creo que al final será el mejor camino.

Comment: @A.Cedano Totalmente deacuerdo contigo, y si ves el codigo ya te mueres, pero tengo unos responsables encima que prefieren usar parches que dedicar tiempo al proyecto.

Comment: A veces ocurre eso, porque los datos no se pueden aparcar mientras se arregla el problema y hay necesidad de ellos urgente. Pero aún así, se puede trazar un plan de salvamento de esos datos. Si no se hace ahora, mientras más tarde peor. Podría llegar un momento en que el sistema se encuentre bloqueado y van a tener que gastarse una fortuna en un equipo de expertos para que arreglen el problema. Es un error seguir adelante solamente aplicando parches, al final el problema va a explotar por un lado o por otro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igual puedes probar con un disparador...

```
CREATE TRIGGER nombredeldisparador AFTER UPDATE ON tabla1 FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE tabla2 SET campodelatabla2 = tabla1.campodelatabla1 WHERE iddelatabla2 = tabla1.iddelatabla1; (con el id o con la relación que haya entre esas dos tablas...)

END
```